# Get original value from keccak_256 if the original value is small in size (less than 256 bits)

Tags: cryptography, solidity, web3js, pycrypto, keccak

When converting an arbitrary long text to 256 bits, information will be lost. So, it is impossible to get it back.
However, if the original text is just few bits long, can we get it back from the keccak_256 hash?

For example:

```
Original text: a
Keccak_256: 3ac225168df54212a25c1c01fd35bebfea408fdac2e31ddd6f80a4bbf9a5f1cb
```

Here the original text is just 8 bits but the hash is 256 bits. So, is that information really lost? If not, how do I get it back.

Comment: See. e.g. [Why can't we reverse hashes?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/45377)

Comment: 8 bits can be easily brute forced; just try all values of the byte until you find the hash, and you know the input. I'm not sure why you would still call it the Keccak hash; usually we call it SHA-3 or SHAKE nowadays (based on the Keccak sponge).